# algebraic groups as representable functors

Tags: category-theory, algebraic-groups

I am struggling with the definition of an algebraic group as given by my teacher.

before defining it, he gives two other things:

1. $1:\text{Alg}_k\rightarrow \text{Set}$ sends all algebras to the singleton. What singleton??
2. For all $F:\text{Alg}_k\rightarrow \text{Set}$ a representable function there exists a natural transformation $\epsilon:G\rightarrow 1$ which projects each $G(R)$ to the singleton $1(R)$. What does this mean?

Comment: It doesn't matter what singleton. All functors that map all algebras to singletons are isomorphic, so that is irrelevant! Pick one and forget about it.

Comment: Did you ask your teacher what all that means? :-|

Comment: Why doesn’t the rest of 2 ever mention $F$ again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A functor $F$ to $\text{Set}$ attaches a set $Fc$ to each object of a category,
and a map $F\phi:Fc\to Fd$ to each morphism $\phi:c\to d$, which all
satisfy various axioms. Anyway in your 1, $1c=\{*\}$ for some $*$
(whose nature is immaterial) and $1\phi$ is the only possible map.
Not the most exciting functor....

In 2, I suspect $G=F$. A natural transformation $\epsilon:F\to1$
allocates a map $\epsilon_c:Fc\to1c$ for each object $c$, and this allocation
satisfies various conditions. Here we have $\epsilon_c:Fc\to\{*\}$
and there is only one possible such map....